# Назначить $scope переменную из вложенного ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-repeat, scope

Есть назначенная в коде переменная `$scope.values = [];` и такой HTML

```
<div class="constructorRow" ng-repeat="param in params">
        <div ng-if="param.alias == 'color'" class="checkRadioColors">
            <span style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px;">Цвет:    </span>
            <label ng-repeat="value in param.values" ng-style="{'background-color': value.value}">
                <input type="radio" ng-model="???" ng-value="{{value.id}}" name="2radioGroup"/>
                <span class="check"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что прописать в ng-model input'а, чтобы можно было записать значение в массив values, указанный выше.

Comment: `<input type="radio" ng-model="values " ng-value="{{value.id}}" name="2radioGroup"/>`

Comment: Есть небольшая проблема - мне нужна функция, которая будет "слушать" изменения этого параметра. Пишу вот так
`$scope.$watch("values", function (newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log(oldValue);
        console.log(newValue);
    });` но это срабатывает лишь один раз при старте приложения. А потом при ручном изменении не реагирует. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Для этого есть у `$scope` метод `$watch`. Почитайте в [документации](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

Comment: Обновил комментарий, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: Потому, что у вас смотриться изменние объекта, тобишь ссылки. А ссылка у вас не меняется. [Тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712089/how-to-deep-watch-an-array-in-angularjs) ответ на ваш вопрос, если в кратце, то третьим параметром для `$watch` надо передать `true`

Comment: Странно, ни передача третьего параметра, ни использование $watchCollection не помогает...

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26913/discussion-between-cheeseq-and-wolkodav).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Обстоятельства

- вам необходимо привести пример самой модели. Какова структура данных?
- если вы используете `name="2radioGroup"`, то как вы намереваетесь заполнять массив? Значение должно быть выбрано одно из всех? Или одно из группы `param in params`?

В любом случае, вам просто надо обращаться к индексу родителя через `$parent`

#### Пример

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.values = [];
    $scope.params = [{
      alias: 'color',
      values: [{
        id: 'i00',
        value: 'red'
      }, {
        id: 'i01',
        value: 'green'
      }, {
        id: 'i02',
        value: 'blue'
      }]
    }, {
      alias: 'color',
      values: [{
        id: 'i10',
        value: '#0f0'
      }, {
        id: 'i11',
        value: '#cfa'
      }, {
        id: 'i12',
        value: '#abc'
      }]
    }, {
      alias: 'font',
      values: [{
        id: 'i10',
        value: '#0f0'
      }, {
        id: 'i11',
        value: '#cfa'
      }, {
        id: 'i12',
        value: '#abc'
      }]
    }];
    $scope.$watchCollection('values', function(n, ol) {
      document.getElementById('watchNew').innerHTML = 'WATCH New value:' + JSON.stringify(n);
      document.getElementById('watchOld').innerHTML = 'WATCH Old value:' + JSON.stringify(ol);
    })
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="param in params">
    <div ng-if="param.alias == 'color'">
      <span style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px;">Цвет:    </span>
      <label ng-repeat="value in param.values" ng-style="{'background-color': value.value}">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="values[$parent.$index]" ng-value="value.id">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <pre>values: {{values | json}}</pre>
  <hr/>
  <pre id="watchNew"></pre>
  <pre id="watchOld"></pre>
  <hr/>
  <pre>params: {{params | json}}</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

#### ЗЫ

`$watch` не отслеживает состояние объектов. Событие произойдет только при смене ссылки на другую переменную. Если вам необходимо отслеживать состояние текущей переменной используйте `$watchCollection`, или, как уже сказано, добавьте третий параметр `true` в `$wach`.

#### Ссылки

- идите в документацию [/ API Reference / ng / input components in ng / input[radio]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)
- попробуйте прочитать [Using scope.$watch and scope.$apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply)
- пример, объясняющий, как появляются `$parent` в `ng-repeat` [AngularJS - Using ng-repeat to create sets of radio inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775981/angularjs-using-ng-repeat-to-create-sets-of-radio-inputs)